# Moving and deleting keys in JS object returned by Sequelize query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a database query that returns me an array with a following format:

```
[
    { score: 1, User: { username: 'user111' } },
    { score: 2, User: { username: 'user222' } }
]
```

I'd like to move each score's User.username to just username. Here's what I'm doing:

```
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scores)));
        for (var i = 0, len = scores.length; i < len; i++) {
            scores[i].username = scores[i].User.username;
            delete scores[i].User;
        }
        console.log("------------------");
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scores)));
```

That unfortunately doesn't seem to work, not sure why:

[image: code result]

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/7cju75nm/

Comment: What the hell.... Could node.js have something to do with it?

Comment: Are your objects [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or something like that?

Comment: Works for me in node also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay for those interested who might stumble upon this:

As I said I was getting scores as a database result from Seqelize ORM. That apparently is not a simple Javascript object so for each score I had to do this trick:

```
scores[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(scores[i]));
```

Edit:

Sequelize's returned objects from queries contain all the model's internal information as well. To get rid of that with a more performance-friendly approach use get with plain: true option (Sequelize 3.x). Here's full solution:

```
        for (var i = 0, len = scores.length; i < len; i++) {
            scores[i] = scores[i].get({ plain: true });
            scores[i].username = scores[i].User.username;
            delete scores[i].User;
        }
```

Comment: Changed my solution. Yours did not work under Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

```
scores[i].User = undefined
```

This will clear your data.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to copy what you need to new Objects:

```
const keys = Object.keys(scores[0]).filter(key => key != 'User');
scores = scores.map(score => {
  const res = {};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    res[key] = score[key];
  });
  res.username = score.User.username;
  return res;
});
```

This assumes that all scores have the same keys, but the performance should be not that bad. Its `O(n*m)` where `n` is the number of items in the array and `m` the number of key you want to copy.